# XCode [[ClassName alloc] init]] keyboard shortcut / autocomplete

Tags: objective-c, xcode, autocomplete, keyboard-shortcuts

Does a keyboard shortcut exist or is there a way to create a custom shortcut for allocating and initializing a class? Say we have:

`MyCustomClass customClass =`

At this point there should be an autocomplete option to:

`MyCustomClass customClass = [[MyCustomClass alloc] init];`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a snippet, but you will need to type in your custom class anyways. A faster way for init is to use `[MyCustomClass new]`.

Comment: xcode does not auto suggest class name after equalsto